# Google Place api not giving search result

Tags: android, api, autocomplete

I just migrate my Google Place autocomplete in my Android Project, but it is not showing search result.
I already enable billing in my project.
but it is showing Can't load search result"
Please help
Thanks in advance.

Please check my gradle file code below
I have already removed previous place api gradle and added new place library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inwizards.findcoach"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.42.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.sujithkanna:smileyrating:1.6.5'
    implementation 'com.github.ekimual:croperino:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.nex3z:flow-layout:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])

    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'){
        exclude module: 'volley'
    }
}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please post an exact log or crash log so we can help in a better way.

Comment: Can you link your project gradle file?

Comment: I didn't get any error

Answer (score 0):

Actually i also faced the same problem butwhen i used another key it work fine for me

Comment: I have used many keys, My Api key working in new fresh project but not working on old project